# Import xls file and view contents Django excel

Tags: django, excel

I would use django excel xls to import a file to display it and then save it to the database
for now I'm only imports a xls file and save it in database.
Here the code shown

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():

         request.FILES['file'].save_to_database(
             #name_columns_by_row=5,
             model=Personne,
             mapdict=['email', 'id', 'nom', 'prenom', 'telephone']
         )
        return HttpResponse("OK")
        #return render(request, 'display.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('import.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to display the contents of an Excel file before the recording is done